# Maintaining RKObjectManager/AFHTTPClient request ordering

Tags: ios, restkit, afnetworking

I've got an iOS app that uses RestKit with Core Data persistence. It loads its data from a few different endpoints, most of which return complete object graphs as nested JSON objects. But one of the endpoints returns objects that contain foreign key references (not nested JSON) to another endpoint's data.

In other words (abbreviated):

```
[postMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"postID", ... ]];

// ...

[commentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ ... ]];
[commentMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"post" connectedBy:@"postID"];
```

where the relevant `Post` and `Comment` entities are set up with the appropriate relationships and so forth.

This all works exactly as it should *but only if* the request to fetch posts finishes *before* the request to fetch comments. Otherwise a comment won't be connected to its post, because the post hasn't been fetched and mapped yet.

Right now, I'm getting around it by just not fetching the comments until the posts have been fetched. Something like

```
- (void)fetchPosts {
    [objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"/posts.json"
                         parameters:nil
                            success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                [self fetchComments]; // *now* we can fetch comments
                                // ...
```

But I'm wondering if there's a better way?

I figure I might be able to do something like

```
 [objectManager.HTTPClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

but most of the time, I *do* want concurrent requests. It's only two of the requests that must be sequential.

I guess I could set up two different object managers (one that does sequential requests and one that does concurrent ones), but I'm not sure that makes sense.

So, is there are way to specify that two specific `-getObjectsAtPath:...` requests should be handled sequentially, while all other can run whenever?

Answer (score 1):

Look at creating another request descriptor which drills down into the comment details and processes only the `postID` attributes. For each one, run the `postMapping` to create a stub object.

Note that you might still run into race conditions with 2 different background contexts both creating the same objects at the same time, so you may need to handle merge issues (this is if you have multiple object managers as you talked about multiple endpoints).

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into that tomorrow. Question about the last parenthetical though: Currently I only have 1 object manager, which loads data from 3 different URLs, but you make it sound like that's not quite right? I'm new to RestKit (and Core Data for that matter), so I've got no clue if I got anything right so far - except that it seems to working :)

Comment: That sounds good, it just wasn't clear if you were getting details from multiple servers. One base URL usually means one object manager (though yhat isn't a hard requirement)

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, it's one base URL so it sounds like I got that part right :)